# Running total of single die - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an application that has a die, singular for dice, on the screen. When you click the die, it will roll and display a number. I also want to keep a running total of each roll.

So far I have it to where each time the button is clicked, the image randomly changes. I'm confused about how to keep a running total of the rolls, however.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function displaydie() { 
            var total = 0;
            var num = ("src",(Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1) + ".jpg")
            document.getElementById("die").setAttribute("src", (Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1) + ".jpg")
        }
    </script>
    <img id="die" alt="die"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="displaydie()"/>
    <span id="total"/></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a global variable to store the total value then add the value of the current dice to the total. For that you need to store the value of the current dice in a variable and use it for the image and to add.

```
var total = 0;

function displaydie() {
    var num = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    total += num;

    document.getElementById("die").setAttribute("src", num + ".jpg")
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r60f2xj0/)

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a dictionary, and on each roll, add to the number of times you have rolled that number:

```
var rolls = {1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0}
var total=0;
function displaydie()

{ 

var num= Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1
rolls[num]+=1
total+=1
document.getElementById("die").setAttribute("src",num + ".jpg")
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Total rolls: "+total+"\n"+"1: "+rolls[1]+" 2: "+rolls[2]+" 3: "+rolls[3]+" 4: "+rolls[4]+" 5: "+rolls[5]+" 6: "+rolls[5]
    }
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sjhps761/)